# how to allow user to set an image in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

Im developing a app which has a user sign-up activity, there I need to allow a user to add a profile picture to his profile at the sign-up phase and show the image in profile activity, How can I do that?
Thanx

Comment: can you provide more details? Does your app has a backend etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StartCamera is Button. When Button is pressed Camera will be started. Take Image and set your `ImageView` as shown in below code:

```
startCamera.setOnClickListener(
   new OnClickListener() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be allowing the user to select a profile picture from some location on the device, so try this:

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(pathName);
```

Then just set that drawable as the source for an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Edit:

Launch an intent to find an image, this will allow the user to select where they want to pull the image from.

```
Intent imgIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
imgIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(imgIntent, 10);
```

In your activity you will need to override onActivityResult to handle the response.

Comment: Thnx, But I need to know how to allow user to select a profile picture